# RESTful Way to Handle Updating Detail Records

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, rpc

If I need to update many detail rows, my Web API controller method might look like this, using an RPC style:

```
[Route("api/updateAccountDetailStatus")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateAccountDetailStatus(int accountId, string status)
```

That would change all of the detail rows, associated with that account, to the new status.

In trying to take a RESTful approach, my guess is that it would be something like this:

```
PATCH /accounts/110
{
  "status": "hold"
}

[Route("api/accounts/id")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Account(Account account)
```

What I don't like about that is now the API controller method needs to interrogate the object to see how to handle it. In this case, it would be changing all of the detail rows to that new status. But what if someone calls that patch and sends a different property to modify? Now I have to change behavior based on that? Is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry can you please explain what you mean by `interrogate object` and `what if someone calls that patch and sends a different property to modify`? Do you mean there needs to be a transaction involved?

Comment: Sure. If the caller is changing the status, then the API method needs to call a certain logic method to update all of the detail records in the DB. Now, what if the caller updates another property instead of status? Perhaps now we just need to update that one property? Or perhaps that means we need to kick off another action entirely? So the API method needs to know which property changed so it can perform the appropriate action. Does that help?

Comment: I see, what you are saying is this is not really PATCH which I agree, it is a special action which kinda needs its own verb, as it were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the conundrum. On one hand, you would like to stay true and not have action names (change, update, etc) in your URI, and on the other hand, this is a special procedure and not quite a PATCH really.

So, for this [article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-api-on-cqrs) I did some work to allow the action to be defined by the type of the message sent, even created a means of doing that in Web API.

The sample code for this is [here](https://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-api-on-cqrs).

Essentially you expose these as POST or PUT (depending on whether they are idempotent or not) and the resource will have multiple POST or PUT against it. For Example:

```
GET /api/InventoryItem [gets all items]
GET /api/InventoryItem/{id} [gets detail of a single item]
POST /api/InventoryItem [creates an item]
POST /api/InventoryItem/{id}* [checks in stock items to the inventory]
POST /api/InventoryItem/{id}* [removes stock items from the inventory]
PUT /api/InventoryItem/{id} [renames an item]
DELETE /api/InventoryItem/{id} [de-activates an item]
```

This is the only solution I have had so far for these types of resources.

## UDPATE

Essential you would expose this as PUT (since I imagine it is idempotent) at `api/accounts/id` sending a payload signifying type of the message:

```
PUT api/accounts/id

{"detailBatchStateChange": "hold"}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you provide an example call based on my scenario? One option could be something like this: `/accounts/{accountId}/detailBatchStateChanges`. That method would know to update all of the detail records with the status (the status would also have to be passed in somehow). But now I might be getting a way from "proper" REST, which may be an indication that REST doesn't work well for this case?

Comment: Updated. I believe it does - I mean REST covers it. One of the tenets is self-descriptive messages hence we should be able to know what to do against the same resource using a different message.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So your approach would mean that the API method would have to interrogate the object to know what type of action to take, right? Whereas if I did something like this: `/accounts/{accountId}/detailBatchStateChanges`, then the method would know what to do without inspecting the incoming object, right? Why would the former be better?

Comment: You do not have to, my sample shows how it finds out the type of the object and finds the right action based on the information passed in the Content-Type (it is an extension parameter). It keeps the purity but whether is worth the trouble is up to you.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it appears that it's the true REST way of doing it. I'm going to go with the more RPC-ish approach though. :) Thanks for your thoughts.